# flex match regex

Tags: regex, apache-flex, loops

I have asked this question before and got some reponses but i am still not cleared on how to do this, if someone could help me more i would appreciate.
What i am doing is reading some information from a URL then i am using a regex(match) to get the string that i need. However i need the result for each match to be a string because i need to manipulate this string. below is the code tha t i have. Any help is appeciated.Again i have asked this but i am not sure how to proceed on my side.

```
var composer:StandardFlowComposer = txtSource.textFlow.flowComposer as StandardFlowComposer;
    var pattern:RegExp=  new RegExp("href=\"/player/.*?\">");
    var pattern2:RegExp=  new RegExp("href=\"/player/.*?\"");
    var myArrayOfLines:Array = ul.data.split(/\n/);
    var line:Array;
    var str:String = "";
    var lineFinal:Array;
    var lineURL:String;
    lineFinal =  myArrayOfLines;
    for each (var lineRaw:String in myArrayOfLines)
    { 
    trace(lineRaw);
        }
    trace(line);
```

Anymore help is appreciated. thank you very much.

Comment: The code sample you've provided doesn't do much to illustrate the problem you described. Can you provide more information or a different code sample?

Comment: What i am trying to accomplish is to read an entire html page. From the html page i need to fins ALL the matches based on my pattern(below). After that i need the matches to be  converted as string and not an array because i will still need to manipulated the string after i get the results from the matches.Let me know if this enough. thank you very much.

    `var pattern2:RegExp=  new RegExp("href=\"/player/.*?\"");`

Answer (score 0):

Try this , this will matches the specifed pattern against the string and returns array of strings...

```
var myArrayOfLines:Array = ul.data.match(/"your pattern here"/gs);

for each (var lineRaw:String in myArrayOfLines)
{ 
trace(lineRaw);
    }
trace(line);
```

[Try your regex here](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/)